# Saved my excel spreadsheets in a USB and lost the USB without backup?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I lost my USB as mentioned above which contains crucial information but I lost it without backup in my desktop. Now that I had open the file before in Excel and it still has the path saved. I'm wondering whether I could be able to recover that file even though the file path did not exist anymore?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: did you save it on your hard drive before transferring it to usb drive ?

Comment: It might have auto-saved at some point, what OS are you on?

Answer (score 3):

If you've saved the file to an USB, just the path where the file was doesn't help you. At all.

So, in answer to your question - no, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The path in Excel is just a shortcut to where the file WAS, nothing more, so there is nothing to actually recover as the data is on your usb drive. You could try going to start, run, type in %temp% and see if there is anything in there, but I don't hold out much hope.